# How to check if request is coming from the same client browser?

Tags: java

I need to implement captcha functionality like in Gmail. 
If the user has requested first time, no captcha image will be shown.
But, if user is requesting second time to login, (User has entered wrong password first time) need to show the captcha.

Please let me know how to check if the request has come from the same user so that I can implement some business logic in my spring classes.

Comment: Check if you can make use of session Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to tie up login attempts to concrete user? If I'm a malefactor and I want to guess the password, I'll use the bruteforcer which can use proxies.

Each time I'll have new IP, so your captcha will not work for me.

In my opinion the better solution is to store counter of incorrect login attempts. Each time anybody inputs wrong password for particular login-name, you increase the counter value for this login. If password is correct, you set this value to 0. If counter value more than 0, you'll show your captcha.

Comment: Amazing answer Maksim. Thanks a lot..you have turned my problem into a extremely simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the counter to the HTTP session. You may required to store the session on the server side, and in a distributed ENV, you should SYNC the HTTP session across servers. You can also store that info into Client side cookies.

Answer (score 0):

At server side(servlet) create `HttpSession`

```
HttpSession session = request.getHttpSession();
```

and keep count of hit inside this session

```
session.setAttribute("count",i);  //you can use getAttribute() method to check the count.
```

Comment: the attribute will be common to all users? how I can make it specific count for single user?

Comment: No. it is different for different browser request. Session object is created for the first incoming request and later-on each request is identified by the same session object. So `count` is stored inside session.

Comment: So in other words it is *not* different for every browser request.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do that:

- When the page is first loaded, start a session (or send out a coookie). Use a count against the session/cookie. You can spit out a captcha once you find the cookie for the second time.
- Use hidden form fields. Put a special name/value pair that you can identify on the second request and send a Captcha across.
- Use AJAX! This would involve using an XMLhttprequest to submit your form, if invalid, you can show a captcha! This would probably give you more control, but at the expense of re-working a bit.

The last two bullets are assuming you want captcha on wrong passwords rather than on a different request/page-reload.

Every one of the above methods has its own pros and cons. You need to choose one or a combination or more than one according to your need.